# How do I format the hhhmm (12h35) format in DateTime?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now() // 2.50 pm

DateFormat('hhhmm').format(currentTime) // prints 00250
```

The only way I can achieve is

```
`${DateFormat('hh').format(DateTime.now())}h${DateFormat('mm').format(DateTime.now())}`
```

Is there any way to acheive like this `DateFormat('hhhmm').format(DateTime.now())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [`DateFormat` documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html):

> The following characters are available in explicit patterns:
>
> ```
> Symbol   Meaning                Presentation       Example
> ------   -------                ------------       -------
> ...
> '        escape for text        (Delimiter)        'Date='
> ```

That is, you can use single-quotes to escape text that you want to be treated literally:

```dart
DateTime currentTime = DateTime(2021, 08, 20, 02, 50);
print(DateFormat("hh'h'mm").format(currentTime)); // Prints: 02h50
```

That said, I personally would find `02h50` to represent a time to be confusing since that style looks like a duration.